In Aptos Blockchain, how is data/state/bytes organized in each account?
In EVM blockchains, each account has a hashmap-like storage to store states. The hashmap can be thought of as a mapping(uint256 => uint256). We can get the stored 256-bits data at any specific storage slot in O(1) time complexity.
In Solana, each account has an byte-array-like storage to store states, like files in the operating systems. The on-chain program authors should define the rule to interpret these bytes.
So what's the case in Aptos? how is the data organized? Is it organized in a hashmap or byte array?
I understand the global storage can be thought of as the following structure
struct Account {
    modules: HashMap<(address, ModuleName), ModuleBytecode>,
    resources: HashMap<(address, FullyQualifiedTypeName), Resource>,
}

I'm wondering if the instance of the Resource type (with key ability) is serialized to some bytes and then these bytes are stored? In this way, it's similar with Solana.
